Get reference to dragged element when dropped on iframe
I'm dragging and dropping a DIV from a parent window onto a nested iframe but I can't get any info on the dragged DIV. In the source of the iframe I have this
window.addEventListener('load', e => {
  let frm = document.body;
  frm.addEventListener("drop", droppedOn);
});

function droppedOn(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(ev)
  ...

If I drag and drop a file from my desktop onto the iframe then there is data in dataTransfer which identifies the dropped file.
When I drag a DIV from the parent onto the iframe, dataTransfer is empty (which I guess is expected) but ev's srcElement, target, and toElement all reference a DIV that is used as a background in the iframe source, frmElement is null, and relatedTarget is null.
How can I get a reference to the DIV that was dragged from the parent window?

I made this answer that is related. Does it help you?

Yes that does it.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to move HTML between bowser tabs in Angular?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
